# What does p.s stand for in french ? And what does it mean in english?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence, translation-request, mathematical-french

Soit $X$ et $Y$ des v.a.r dindependantes et supposons que $P(X+Y=a)=1$ ou $a$ est une constante. Montrer que $X$ et $Y$  sont p.s des constantes .

So unfortunately I don't know french , what does p.s mean in english ? Is it almost everywhere (a.e) ?

Comment: This is not a mathematics question per se, but a translation question. The existing answer is adequate and solves the OP's needs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It stands for "presque sûrement", which means "almost surely".